# How to achieve horizontally stretchable page layout that works on desktop ond mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout, windows-phone-8

I've tried using table's, div's and other things but so far keep running into various issues when the full desktop site is viewed on a mobile device.  I have a mobile version of the site but I still don't have all of the functionality I want built in there so I have force desktop site option to view the full site.  The main issues I run into are that when I zoom out from the site the header doesn't stretch and is no longer centered.  Also, the footer doesn't stay at the bottom of the browser in a mobile device as I would like it to.  My mobile site which uses JQueryMobile does stay at the bottom but not in the case of the full desktop site.  Does anyone have a similar layout that they could share that achieves what I have in the image below that I can start fresh with?

[image: desired page layout]

Comment: On what type of windows mobile do you test, need the EXACT OS version? There are issues with Windows Mobile/Embedded Handheld OS. The browsers on there are very limitted and have options to re-flow any layout to there 'needs'.

Answer (score 0):

I can only help you with the footer issue working with jQuery mobile.
For me there were two solutions that worked:

1.

```
        <footer data-role="footer" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%">
            <!--footer goes just here-->
            <h1>Page Footer</h1>
        </footer>
```

2.

```
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <!--footer goes just here-->
            <!--footer will allways be displayed-->
            <h1>Page Footer</h1>
        </footer>
```